# Hadoop Wordcount example failing due to AM container

Tags: windows, hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn

I've been trying to run the hadoop wordcount example for a while now, however I am facing some issues. I have hadoop 2.7.1 and running it on Windows. Below are the error details:

**command:**

```
yarn jar C:\hadoop-2.7.1\share\hadoop\mapreduce\hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.7.1.jar wordcount input output
```

**Output:**

```
INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:1
INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_14
90853163147_0009
INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_14
90853163147_0009
INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://*****
*****/proxy/application_1490853163147_0009/
INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1490853163147_0009
INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1490853163147_0009 running in uber
 mode : false
INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1490853163147_0009 failed with sta
te FAILED due to: Application application_1490853163147_0009 failed 2 times due
to AM Container for appattempt_1490853163147_0009_000002 exited with  exitCode:
1639
For more detailed output, check application tracking page:http://********
:****/cluster/app/application_1490853163147_0009Then, click on links to logs of
each attempt.
Diagnostics: Exception from container-launch.
Container id: container_1490853163147_0009_02_000001
Exit code: 1639
Exception message: Incorrect command line arguments.


Stack trace: ExitCodeException exitCode=1639: Incorrect command line arguments.


        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:545)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:456)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:
722)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor.la
unchContainer(DefaultContainerExecutor.java:211)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.C
ontainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:302)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.C
ontainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:82)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.
java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor
.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Shell output:     Usage: task create [TASKNAME] [COMMAND_LINE] |
          task isAlive [TASKNAME] |
          task kill [TASKNAME]
          task processList [TASKNAME]
    Creates a new task jobobject with taskname
    Checks if task jobobject is alive
    Kills task jobobject
    Prints to stdout a list of processes in the task
    along with their resource usage. One process per line
    and comma separated info per process
    ProcessId,VirtualMemoryCommitted(bytes),
    WorkingSetSize(bytes),CpuTime(Millisec,Kernel+User)


Container exited with a non-zero exit code 1639
Failing this attempt. Failing the application.
INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 0
```

**Yarn-site.xml:**

```
<configuration>
<property>
       <name>yarn.application.classpath</name>
       <value>
            C:\hadoop-2.7.1\etc\hadoop,
            C:\hadoop-2.7.1\share\hadoop\common\*,
            C:\hadoop-2.7.1\share\hadoop\common\lib\*,
            C:\hadoop-2.7.1\share\hadoop\hdfs\*,
            C:\hadoop-2.7.1\share\hadoop\hdfs\lib\*,
            C:\hadoop-2.7.1\share\hadoop\mapreduce\*,
            C:\hadoop-2.7.1\share\hadoop\mapreduce\lib\*,
            C:\hadoop-2.7.1\share\hadoop\yarn\*,
            C:\hadoop-2.7.1\share\hadoop\yarn\lib\*
       </value>
    </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
    <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
  </property>
  <property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.disk-health-checker.max-disk-utilization-per-disk-percentage</name>
        <value>98.5</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb</name>
  <value>2200</value>
  <description>Amount of physical memory, in MB, that can be allocated for containers.</description>
</property>

<property>
  <name>yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb</name>
  <value>500</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>yarn.log-aggregation-enable</name>
    <value>true</value>
</property>

<property>
    <description>Where to aggregate logs to.</description>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.remote-app-log-dir</name>
    <value>/tmp/logs</value>
</property>

<property>
    <name>yarn.log-aggregation.retain-seconds</name>
    <value>259200</value>
</property>

<property>
    <name>yarn.log-aggregation.retain-check-interval-seconds</name>
    <value>3600</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

**mapred.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>
<!--
  Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
  you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
  You may obtain a copy of the License at

    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  limitations under the License. See accompanying LICENSE file.
-->

<!-- Put site-specific property overrides in this file. -->

<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
    <value>yarn</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

Any idea on what is going wrong?

Comment: you got solution for this

Answer (score 0):

exitCode:  1639  Looks like your are running hadoop on Windows .

https://github.com/OctopusDeploy/Issues/issues/1346

Comment: How does this answer the question above? OP has already mentioned that it is configured on Windows.

Comment: Yes as I said, I am running it on Windows. I have tried a lot of fixes, but this error won't go!

Answer (score 0):

I faced exactly same problem. I was following a guide on how to install Hadoop 2.6.0 ([http://www.ics.uci.edu/~shantas/Install_Hadoop-2.6.0_on_Windows10.pdf](http://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Eshantas/Install_Hadoop-2.6.0_on_Windows10.pdf)) while actually installing Hadoop 2.8.0.
As soon as I was done I ran

> hadoop jar D:\hadoop-2.8.0\share\hadoop\mapreduce\hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.8.0.jar wordcount /foo/bar/LICENSE.txt /out1

And got (from yarn nodemanager's logs):

> 17/06/19 13:15:30 INFO monitor.ContainersMonitorImpl: Starting resource-monitoring for container_1497902417767_0004_01_000001
>
> 17/06/19 13:15:30 INFO nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor: launchContainer: [D:\hadoop-2.8.0\bin\winutils.exe, task, create, -m, -1, -c, -1, container_1497902417767_0004_01_000001, cmd /c D:/hadoop/temp/nm-localdir/usercache/******/appcache/application_1497902417767_0004/container_1497902417767_0004_01_000001/default_container_executor.cmd]
>
> 17/06/19 13:15:30 WARN nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor: Exit code from container container_1497902417767_0004_01_000001 is : 1639
>
> 17/06/19 13:15:30 WARN nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor: Exception from container-launch with container ID: container_1497902417767_0004_01_000001 and exit code: 1639
>
> ExitCodeException exitCode=1639: Incorrect command line arguments.
>
> TaskExit: error (1639): Invalid command line argument. Consult the Windows Installer SDK for detailed command line help.

Another symptom was (from yarn nodemanager's logs):

> 17/06/19 13:25:49 WARN util.SysInfoWindows: Expected split length of sysInfo to be 11. Got 7

The solution was to get compatible (with Hadoop 2.8.0) binaries: https://github.com/steveloughran/winutils/tree/master/hadoop-2.8.0-RC3/bin

**Once I got a correct winutils.exe, my problem went away.**